# Fetching 'Person or Group' column value from sharepoint online list using JSON and AJAX

Tags: json, sharepoint

```
 $.ajax  
    ({  
        url: "--URL of the list--GetByTitle('Listname')/items?$select=Title&$expand=EMAILColumn",  
        type: 'GET',  
        data: JSON,  
        headers:  
        {  
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),  
            "IF-MATCH": "*",  
            "X-HTTP-Method": null  
        },  
        cache: false,  
        success: function(data)   
        {
```

---

I am trying to fetch the data of sharepoint list using the above query. I am able to fetch the data of columns that are 'Sinle line of text' or 'Multiline text'. But I can't fetch the data of columns that are 'Person or Group' category. It gave me the error:

```
The query to field 'EMAILColumn' is not valid. 
The $select query string must specify the target fields and the $expand query string must contains EMAILColumn.
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried using /items?$select=Title,EMAILColumn ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly check the below modified code.

```js
$.ajax
({
url: "--URL of the list--GetByTitle('Listname')/items?$select=ID,Title,EMAILColumn/Email&$expand=EMAILColumn/Id,",
type: 'GET',
data: JSON,
headers:
{
"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
"Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
"X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
"IF-MATCH": "*",
"X-HTTP-Method": null
},
cache: false,
success: function(data)
```

Let’s say a list has custom field: Author, it will return ‘AuthorId’ in response. What is the proper way to deal with people field? You need to use ‘$expand’ parameter to expand the field.

Following REST URL gives your idea how to use $expand.

```html
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('infolist')/items?$select=Author/Title&$expand=Author/Id
```